# Pygame tuple and int

Tags: python, pygame

```
import os
import random
pygame.font.init()
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 900, 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("CLICKER")
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
thing_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("BLACKDOT.png"))
thing = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.transform.scale(thing_img, (20, 20)),90)
score = 0
a = 0




def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    run = True
    while run:
        x_pos = random.randint(10 ,780)
        y_pos = random.randint(10, 480)
        x = int(x_pos * 1)
        y = int(y_pos * 1)
        WIN.blit(WHITE, (x, y))
        running = True
        while running:
            clock.tick(60)
            a += 1
            if a >= 1800:
                print(score)
                exit()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    exit()
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    print(mouse_pos)
                    if mouse_pos[0] >= x_pos and mouse_pos[0] <= x_pos + 10 and mouse_pos[1] >= y_pos and mouse_pos[1] <= y_pos + 10:
                        running = False
                        score += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get some error messages when running the code, it says
"line 26, in main
WIN.blit(WHITE, (x, y))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not tuple".
How I can overcome this problem?

Comment: `blit` takes a surface, e.g. an Image. `White` is a tuple, e.g. a Color. Use `.fill` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) draws a source *Surface* onto another *Surface*. It can be used to draw a _Surface (image) on the screen.
If you want to fill the screen with a uniform color, you need to use [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill):

<s>`WIN.blit(WHITE, (x, y))`</s>

```py
WIN.fill(WHITE)
```